# Determining why Firebug won't gray/green lines

Tags: javascript, debugging, firebug

I'm tearing my hair out here due to Firebug's seeming propensity to refuse to hit breakpoints in critical sections where it would be really, really helpful to be able to step through the code to help see what is going on.  I have read elsewhere that Firebug won't hit a breakpoint if the line number isn't the right color: it used to be green, but lately I notice it seems to be the difference between light gray and dark grey, where light-gray lines are the ones the Firebug won't break on.

I am looking for any suggestions as to how to get Firebug to recognize that it should be able to break on a line.   Often it will refuse to honor breakpoints on ten or twenty lines in a row, as if it suddenly got confused parsing a function and just gave up until the function was over.  In some cases, simply commenting out one line (and then reloading of course) makes Firebug suddenly recognize the rest of the function, but without any rhyme or reason that I can see, even to the point that simply adding something innocuous like an extra semi-colon makes it go back to not recognizing the lines again.  In some cases it seems that do/while loops confuse it, but even in a function without such a loop I am currently having trouble.

I have already tried all the other things I could find in other threads, such as resetting all, restarting the browser, using the latest version, etc.

Update: In one case I was able to get Firebug to recognize lines by changing:

```
do {
    ...
} while (condition)
```

to

```
while (1) {
    ...
    if (!(condition)) break
}
```

Firefox 23 / Firebug 1.11.4

Update: It seems that whenever I find a section of code like this, I can get the problem to go away by creating a new empty javascript file (adding a reference in the HTML file) and moving the affected function to that file.  Suddenly the lines get greened (it's back to green again now, no idea why...)

Comment: I feel your pain. I hope somebody would shed some light on this.

Comment: Alas, my solution was to ditch Firefox and use Chrome, which has - in my opinion - a much superior debugger built in.

Comment: Good. Chrome has good debugger, but does not have something that Firebug has - Search in all sources. This is a GREAT feature in Firebug, and has no alternative. This is VERY useful for dynamic JS sources. I have the same problem with the Green/Gray lines though :/